# Why can't I ask this question?

Tags: support, area-51, specific-question, scope

Hi everybody,

I found stackoverflow.com with the help of Google an hour ago. In the footer I found some links that I clicked through and eventually came to this Q&A site called **[App Dissect](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17148/app-dissect)**.

In there it says

> Proposed Q&A site for people who are
>   interested in getting a deep and
>   detailed understanding of how an
>   application works internally.

This is the ideal place for my question, and it is proposed by stackoverflow, but the strange thing is, there is no Ask Question link or button. Could a friend explain what is wrong? Do you know a similar site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Area51 is a site where people can propose new ideas for Stackexchange sites. That means the site does not yet exists, but still needs to be defined and supported before it can go live.

If you like the site idea, register yourself on area51 and help to get it the things it needs. Right now it still needs votes on good and bad questions.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Ask Question link because the site is only **proposed**. It has to get a certain level of support before it becomes live.

Answer (score 4):

The App Dissect site is currently in the process of being established, so really there isn't an actual site yet. You can register on Area 51 to support that process if you'd like.

In the meantime, I think it's probably safe to post your question on Stack Overflow.